# What needs to be enable for remote WUApiLib

Tags: c#, windows-administration, wuapi

What needs to be enabled on the remote PC so that I could use WUApiLib remotely? I have this code that returns me the error 80070005

```
Type t = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Microsoft.Update.Session", "192.168.1.14");
        UpdateSession uSession = (UpdateSession)Activator.CreateInstance(t);
        IUpdateSearcher uSearcher = uSession.CreateUpdateSearcher();
        uSearcher.Online = false;
        IUpdateHistoryEntryCollection history = uSearcher.QueryHistory(0, uSearcher.GetTotalHistoryCount());
        for (int i = 0; i < history.Count; ++i)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(history[i].Title);
        }
```